# .NET5 JsonPatchDocument.ApplyTo throws when add or replace

Tags: c#, json, .net, .net-5, http-patch

I got a problem with my JsonPatchDocument object, which can Remove value from the field, but cannot add/replace it.

My controller code is as following:

```
[HttpPatch]
[Route("{layersGroupId}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Patch([FromServices] IMediator mediator,
    [FromBody] List<Operation<LayerGroup>> operations,
    Guid layersGroupId,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    await mediator.Send(new PatchLayersGroupCommand
    {
        LayersGroupId = layersGroupId,
        JsonPatch = new JsonPatchDocument<LayerGroup>(operations, new DefaultContractResolver())
    }, cancellationToken);

    return Ok();
}
```

Code in handler:

```
var layersGroup = await databaseContext.UsersLayersViews
                .Where(x => x.UserId == identity.Current.UserId && x.LayerGroupId == request.LayersGroupId)
                .Select(x => x.LayerGroup)
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);

if (layersGroup == null)
    throw new ValidationException(ErrorCode.InvalidId, "Invalid layers group ID");

request.JsonPatch.ApplyTo(layersGroup); // Code throws here
```

The exception is:

```
Unhandled JsonPatchException caught, none of known global handlers could apply
ExceptionDetail
{HResult: -2146233088, Message: 'The value ''"NewName"'' is invalid for target location.', Source: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch', StackTrace: '   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch.Internal.ErrorReporter.<>c.<.cctor>b__1_0(JsonPatchError error)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch.Adapters.ObjectAdapter.Replace(Operation operation, Object objectToApplyTo)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch.Operations.Operation`1.Apply(TModel objectToApplyTo, IObjectAdapter adapter)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch.JsonPatchDocument`1.ApplyTo(TModel objectToApplyTo, IObjectAdapter adapter)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch.JsonPatchDocument`1.ApplyTo(TModel objectToApplyTo)
   at DHIPL.UrbanTools.GIS.Api.UseCases.Groups.Put.RenameGroup.RenameLayersGroupCommandHandler.Handle(RenameLayersGroupCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Users\msty\source\repos\urban-tools-backend\src\Services\GIS\GIS.Api\UseCases\Groups\Put\RenameGroup\RenameLayersGroupCommandHandler.cs:line 36
   at DHIPL.Core.Api.Behaviors.ValidatorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next) in C:\Users\msty\source\repos\urban-tools-backend\src\Packages\DHIPL.Core.Api\Behaviors\ValidatorBehavior.cs:line 31
   at DHIPL.Core.Api.Behaviors.TransactionBehavior`2.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<Handle>b__0>d.MoveNext() in C:\Users\msty\source\repos\urban-tools-backend\src\Packages\DHIPL.Core.Api\Behaviors\TransactionBehavior.cs:line 14
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at DHIPL.Core.Transactions.TransactionHelper.Wrap[TResult](Func`1 action) in C:\Users\msty\source\repos\urban-tools-backend\src\Packages\DHIPL.Core\Transactions\TransactionHelper.cs:line 51
   at DHIPL.Core.Api.Behaviors.TransactionBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next) in C:\Users\msty\source\repos\urban-tools-backend\src\Packages\DHIPL.Core.Api\Behaviors\TransactionBehavior.cs:line 14
   at DHIPL.Core.Api.Behaviors.LoggingBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next) in C:\Users\msty\source\repos\urban-tools-backend\src\Packages\DHIPL.Core.Api\Behaviors\LoggingBehavior.cs:line 32
   at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestExceptionProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next)
   at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestExceptionProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next)
   at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestExceptionActionProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next)
   at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestExceptionActionProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next)
   at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestPostProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next)
   at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestPreProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next)
   at DHIPL.UrbanTools.GIS.Api.Controllers.GroupController.PutRename(IMediator mediator, List`1 operations, Guid layersGroupId, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Users\msty\source\repos\urban-tools-backend\src\Services\GIS\GIS.Api\Controllers\GroupController.cs:line 41
   at lambda_method668(Closure , Object )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at DHIPL.Core.Api.Exceptions.CoreExceptionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) in C:\Users\msty\source\repos\urban-tools-backend\src\Packages\DHIPL.Core.Api\Exceptions\CoreExceptionMiddleware.cs:line 30', FailedOperation: {…}, AffectedObject: {…}, Type: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch.Exceptions.JsonPatchException'}
```

There is no single post about this error in the Internet. I'm confused now. Did anyone have such a problem before? How to solve it?

Just in case, PatchLayersGroupCommand has these data inside:

```
{
  
LayersGroupId: 'c36bb6c1-4be2-44b9-9239-d7e41d10ebaa',
  
JsonPatch: {
    
Operations: [
      
{
        
value: {
          
ValueKind: 'String',
          
_typeTag: 'JsonElement'
        },
        
OperationType: 'Replace',
        
path: '/GroupName',
        
op: 'replace',
        
from: null,
        
_typeTag: 'Operation`1'
      }
    ],
    
ContractResolver: {
      
DynamicCodeGeneration: false,
      
DefaultMembersSearchFlags: 'Instance, Public',
      
SerializeCompilerGeneratedMembers: false,
      
IgnoreSerializableInterface: false,
      
IgnoreSerializableAttribute: true,
      
IgnoreIsSpecifiedMembers: false,
      
IgnoreShouldSerializeMembers: false,
      
NamingStrategy: null,
      
_typeTag: 'DefaultContractResolver'
    },
    
_typeTag: 'JsonPatchDocument`1'
  },
  
_typeTag: 'RenameLayersGroupCommand'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for `JsonPatch` is enabled using the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` package. To enable this feature, apps must:

Install the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` NuGet package.

Update the project's `Startup.ConfigureServices` method to include a call to `AddNewtonsoftJson`:

```
services
    .AddControllers()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

After adding it to the services take `JsonPatchDocument<T>` directly from body and don't create it yourself. JsonPatch should now work.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked like a charm. I didn't realize NewtonsoftJson is required...

Comment: Nowadays Microsoft has a pretty good article that describes how to setup the configuration, also in case you want to keep using System.Text.Json instead of using Newtonsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/jsonpatch?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Regarding @DeMaki's comment; this still uses Newtonsoft.Json for the patch request.
If you would like to use System.Text.Json all the way, you can use this package: https://github.com/Havunen/SystemTextJsonPatch